# Consistent spacing before section (KOMA)

Tags: itemize, vspace, vskip

I'm using the KOMAscript classes and notice that the space before each section heading depends on the previous environment. (I doubt this issue is exclusive to KOMA, I just thought I should mention it).

This makes sense to me; paragraphs, floats, or items, may produce parskip, topsep, and intextsep differently, effectively changing the space between environment and next section heading. What I've noticed is the space from a itemize or float is larger than paragraph. Simply put, I want the spacing between the last piece of ink in a section and the next section head to be the same, regardless if the ink is from a paragraph, itemize, tabular, figure, caption, etc.

Is there an easy way to force the spacing between a next section head and the previous environment to a specified value?

Better yet, is there a latex command that simply guarantees some skip between bodies, ignoring any preceding or succeeding skips?

To achieve the spacing I want, I need to patch the itemize with after=vspace, but this adds too much space if a section follows..

Comment: For clarification: When you say "is there a latex command that simply guarantees some skip between **bodies**, ignoring any preceding or succeeding skips", by bodies you mean the content of a body, i.e. the vertically most extreme parts of a body that are visible?

Comment: @TivV Yes, exactly. Although if it's a piece of text with a "g" for example, it wouldn't measure from the very bottom, but the baseline.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not exactly sure if I understand your problem correctly. Maybe `\raggedbottom` (see [KOMA-Script Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), chapter 3.4) is the option you are looking for?